# Correct way to show calculated values on vuetify forms

Tags: vuetify.js

I begin to use vuetify some days ago.
Now i'm playing with forms and datatables.
I want to show on a form calculated values based on one database record and i don't know if i'm doing right.
The record returned by an api have this columns:

- senderCuip
- senderDescription
- brokerCuip
- brokerDescription
- recipientCuip
- recipientDescription
- originDescription
- originCity
- originState
- destinationDescription
- destinationCity
- destinationState

and i want to show as:

- Sender as senderCuip (senderDescription)
- Broker as brokerCuip (brokerDescription)
- Recipient as recipientCuip (recipientDescription)
- Origin as originDescription (originCity, originState)
- Destination as destinationDescription (destinationCity, destinationState)

Example:

- senderCuip: '20224528325'
- senderDescription: 'SENDER SA'
- brokerCuip: '30455298762'
- brokerDescription: 'BROKER SA'
- recipientCuip: '33521452363'
- recipientDescription: 'RECIPIENT
  SA'
- originDescription: 'ORIGIN DESCRIPTION'
- originCity: 'ORIGIN CITY'
- originState: 'ORIGEN STATE'
- destinationDescription: 'DESTINATION DESCRIPTION'
- destinationCity: 'DESTINATION CITY'
- destinationState: 'DESTINATION STATE'

must be showed as:

- Sender: 20224528325 (SENDER SA)
- Broker: 30455298762 (BROKER SA)
- Recipient: 33521452363 (RECIPIENT SA)
- Origin: ORIGIN DESCRIPTION (ORIGIN CITY, ORIGEN STATE)
- Destination: DESTINATION DESCRIPTION (DESTINATION CITY, DESTINATION STATE)

I'm using five computed properties.
The computed properties for Sender, Broker, and Recipient use the same format. The same applies for the computed properties for Origin and Destination.
I'm doing in this way:

```
computed: {
sender: function () {

  return this.item.senderCuip + ' (' + this.item.senderDescription + ')';
},
broker: function () {

  return this.item.brokerCuip + ' (' + this.item.brokerDescription + ')';
},
recipient: function () {

  return this.item.recipientCuip + ' (' + this.item.recipientDescription + ')';
},
origin: function () {

  return this.item.originDescription + ' (' + this.item.originCity + ', ' + this.item.originState + ')';
},
destination: function () {

  return this.item.destinationDescription + ' (' + this.item.destinationCity + ', ' + this.item.destinationState + ')';
}
```

}

but i think that this can be done in more effective ways. I understand that computed properties cannot receive parameters or call methods to do something like that:

```
methods: {

participator(cuip, description) {
    return cuip + ' (' + description + ')'

},

location(description, city, state) {
    return description + ' (' + city + ', ' + state + ')';
}
```

}

```
computed: {
sender: function (cuip, description) {

    return participator(cuip, description);
}
```

}

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/wolverine4277/pen/povBaZY)

Similar case happens on a datatable, in this case i use templates instead of computed properties, but the problem is the same, repetitive code:

```
<template v-slot:item.sender="{ item }">{{ item.senderCuip }} ({{ item.senderDescription }})</template>
<template v-slot:item.broker="{ item }">{{ item.brokerCuip }} ({{ item.brokerDescription }})</template>
<template v-slot:item.recipient="{ item }">{{ item.recipientCuip }} ({{ item.recipientDescription }})</template>
<template v-slot:item.origin="{ item }">{{item.originDescription }} ({{ item.originCity }} , {{ item.originState }})</template>
<template v-slot:item.destination="{ item }">{{item.destinationDescription }} ({{ item.destinationCity }} , {{ item.destinationState }})</template>
```

I'm doing well or there are best options?
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try out generate those properties dynamically to simplify your app (this saves time when it grows), using a reduce function as I did below.

Check it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/felipemm/pen/VwYNxRY) or in the snippet above:

Note: The snippet and the codepen are a little bit different in layout

```js
const createComputedWithInfo = (properties) => (
  Object
    .getOwnPropertyNames(properties)
    .reduce((computedProperties, property) => {
      const primaryInfo = properties[property].primary
      const secondaryInfo = properties[property].secondary
      computedProperties[property] = `${primaryInfo} ( ${Array.isArray(secondaryInfo) ? secondaryInfo.join(', ') : secondaryInfo} )`
      return computedProperties
    }, {})
);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    item: {
      number: "214852145218",
      date: "2020-01-27",      
      properties: {
          sender: {
            primary: "20224528325",
            secondary: "SENDER SA"
          },
          broker: {
            primary: "30455298762",
            secondary: "BROKER SA"
          },
          recipient: {
            primary: "33521452363", 
            secondary: "RECIPIENT SA"
          },
          origin: {
            primary: "ORIGIN DESCRIPTION",
            secondary: ["ORIGIN CITY", "ORIGEN STATE"]
          },
          destination: {
            primary: "DESTINATION DESCRIPTION",
            secondary: ["DESTINATION CITY", "DESTINATION STATE"]
          }
      },
    }
  }),
  computed: {
    itemProperties: function () {
      return {
        ...createComputedWithInfo(this.item.properties)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form
    >
      <v-text-field
        v-model="itemProperties.sender"

      ></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="itemProperties.broker"

      ></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="itemProperties.recipient"

      ></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="itemProperties.origin"        
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="itemProperties.destination"

      ></v-text-field>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @felipemm, thanks for your suggestions, i don't manage the api, so maybe i can "reformat" the data to do in this way. Do your suggestion works on datatable? When i try in my way i can't use computed properties because de multiple items. Regards.